# Rails not rendering correctly on heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

On a new user I validate the uniqueness of a field and if it already exists I add an error with a string from locale.

That has this base format

```
field_error_message_uniqueness_html: "Already bla bla<br/> if bla bla contact us<a href='mailto:%{email}' target='_top'>%{email}</a>."
```

When I test on a development enviroment it works great, but on heroku it displays like it wasn't html.
development

```
Already bla bla
if bla bla contact us info@mail.com
```

heroku

```
Already bla bla<br/> if bla bla contact us <a href='mailto:info@mail.com' target='_top'>info@mail.com</a>.
```

My error adding code

```
 validates_uniqueness_of :field_number,
                          allow_blank: true,
                         :message=>(I18n.t :field_error_message_uniqueness_html, scope: "activerecord.attributes.user", email: ApplicationHelper::SUPPORT_EMAIL ).html_safe
```

What can possibly be messing it?

Comment: Which Rails version? You can try using the method `.html_safe`

Comment: @Gerep on both env. I'm usign rails 3.2.11

Comment: I had already added the .html_safe when i add the error

Comment: Have you tried changing the `"` for `'`? Like this `field_error_message_uniqueness_html: 'Already bla bla<br/> if bla bla contact us<a href="mailto:%{email}" target="_top">%{email}</a>.'`

Comment: still don't work. I cannot understand why in a dev env works and on heroku don't... cause everything else seems to be working properly

Comment: You can also try to use string instead of a symbol like this: `I18n.t "field_error_message_uniqueness_html"`. This is how I work and I never had a problem.

Comment: No, exactly the same... :( I don't think the problem is there cause if it works on my dev, why wouldn't on production on heroku. can it be anything related to some configuration?

Comment: Try using `heroku logs --tail` and make that happens, maybe there's something in there

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .html_safe to your string.

```
field_error_message_uniqueness_html: "Already bla bla<br/> if bla bla contact us<a href='mailto:%{email}' target='_top'>%{email}</a>.".html_safe
```

Comment: try that and it doesn't work, **can not load translations from C:/Projects/Project1/config/locales/pt.yml: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (C:/RubymineProjects/recibosonline/config/locales/pt.yml): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 37 column 9>**